# Listening fro 'connect' on all namespaces

Tags: flask-socketio

I want to check `auth` on SocketIO server for all namespaces. How can I listen with `@socketio.on('connect')` on all namespaces to validate the `auth` content?

I have tried `@socketio.on('connect', namespace='*')` but this did not help. Looking at the *Namespace* class to handle namespaces it does not seems to handle all namespace as well. Any idea?

Comment: There is no support to listening on all namespaces. Namespaces are not designed to be dynamic. Create your connect handlers for all the namespaces that you use and call a common function to the auth from them. Or decorate a single function with several `@socketio.on('connect')`, one per namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='foo')
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='bar')
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='baz')
def connect():
    # common auth here
```